# Unable to flag question for asking for a product recommendation

Tags: feature-request, flagging, off-topic

I was going to flag [a recent question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11216/web-software-tool-for-process-probability-simulation-using-a-flowchart) for asking for a product recommendation, but was unable to do so because there was no option.

The "Off-topic" section of the flag feature, only has two choices:

- question is blatantly off topic
- question belongs on a different SE site

Neither of these applies. So, I guess this is a feature request. Could we please add all the standard reasons for being off-topic to the flag feature?

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, flagging is only for cases that require prompt intervention by a moderator, for example spam or a question that they need to migrate manually. If a question is simply off-topic, the proper course of action would be to vote to close. You are very close to the reputation threshold (500) to participate in close votes, there 'Off Topic as defined in the help center' is an option.

Answer (score 1):

Blatantly off-topic would have worked in this case as it would have moved the question into the close review queue.

It's worth noting that "all the standard reasons for being off-topic" are actually defined on a per-site basis.  SO's off-topic reasons are similar but different than Programmers, for example.  Engineering hasn't gotten to the point to where it needs additional off-topic close vote reasons.

All that said, I migrated that particular question off to Software Recommendations.  I think that the OP provided sufficient requirements and demonstrated enough prior research in order to make it on-topic over at Software Recs.